# Get current DNS server on 16.04-server

Tags: server, 16.04, dns

Is there a simple command to find out which DNS server I'm using **right now**? Preferably without resorting to `tcpdump` or parsing log files?

I found a lot of stuff about `nm-cli` and other nm-tools but that doesn't apply to a server...

Comment: Try just `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Since this has become a popular question, the answer is "resolvectl status" if you are running a server without GUI / NM / etc. And it's the 10th answer on the thread posted above. Why block this thread then, if it could provide better answers?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`nslookup` can be used to get the DNS server that is being used.

**Example:**

```
$ nslookup www.google.com
Server:     10.0.0.1     <--This is the DNS server address.
Address:    10.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 216.58.217.36
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

For the majority of applications,

```
less /etc/resolv.conf
```

should work.  Otherwise, you can try,

```
dig xxxxxxxxx
```

replacing xxxxxxxx with any server of your choice.  You should see what nameserver was used to look it up.

N.B.: Don't be surprised if it is 127.0.0.1 : this is your localhost, which probably means it's your router that is determining your nameserver.